Continuous map $f:T\to S^2$ such that $f_{*2}([z])=n[w]$

For any $n \in \mathbb Z$,  construct a continuous map $f:T\to S^2$,  such that $f_{*2}([z])=n[w]$, where $[z]$ and $[w]$ are elements generating $H_2(T, \mathbb Z)$ and $H_2(S^2,\mathbb Z)$, and $f_{*2}:H_2(T,\mathbb Z)\to H_2(S^2,\mathbb Z)$ is the induced homomorphism. $T = S^1\times S^1$ is the torus and $S^2$ is the sphere.

I can construct a continuous map that maps $[z]$ to $[w]$. But I don't know how to construct such a continuous map for an arbitrary $n$.
Many thanks in advance!

Please edit our question  and tell us what $T$ is. I can guess what it is, but people should not make guesses.

If you view $S^2$ as $D^2/\partial D_2$, that is, the space obtained by identifying the points on the boundary of the 2-disk, then since $T^2$ is the quotient of the unit square by the map identifying opposite edges, and the unit square and unit disk are homeomorphic, by the universal property of quotients we obtain a continuous map $f\colon T^2\to S^2$.
By, for example, triangulating, it is easy to see that $f_{2\bullet}([z])=[w]$, where $[z]$ and $[w]$ are the generators of $H_2(T^2)$ and $H_2(S^2)$ respectively.
Now to obtain a map which sends $[z]$ to $n[w]$, note that it is enough to find a map $a_n \colon T^2 \to T^2$ which sends $[z]$ to $n[z]$. For this, note that $T^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ and it is easy to see that the map $a_n(s,t) =(s,n.t)$ ($(s,t)\in \mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$) has $(a_n)_{2\bullet}([z])=n[z]$ so that $(f\circ a_n)_{2\bullet}([z])=n[w]$

The map $F_n=S^2\to S^2$, $x\to x^n$ is of degree n. Here we identify the 2-sphere $S^2$ with the complex projective line, and $x\to x^n$ is the extension of the holomorphic map $x\to x^n$. So $f_n=F_n\circ f$ satisfies $f_n[T^2]=nf[T^2]$, where $[T^2]$ is the fundamental class.

This makes no sense. Please define your notation carefully.

I tried to do it ..it would be better replace $x$  by $z$ (a complex number), but @krm2233 used the curious $[z]$ instead of $[T^2]$ for the fundamental class of the torus.

Got it. You've made it clear now.
